# Как изменить направление колонок в Angular Material table?

Tags: angular5, angular-material

Кто-нибудь знает как в таблице из этого примера: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlxbkjqaoba?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Сделать так, чтобы колонки были направлены горизонтально, примерно как на картинке: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подходящий ответ смотрите здесь:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043232/how-to-change-the-direction-of-the-columns-in-the-angular-material-table/51044025?noredirect=1#comment89080550_51044025

stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6dvzc-jjqdpk